# Create a new array from multidimensional array searching and matching a specific value php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been working with a with a little debit, credit system. It produces daily transaction which i get from this array. 
'

```
   $trans_arr = array(

       0 => array(
             '2015-21-11',
              'credit#50',
             'debit#70'
             ),

      1 => array(
           '2015-21-11',
           'credit#80',
           'debit#30'
           ),

      3 => array(
         '2015-22-11',
         'credit#80',
         'debit#90'
        ),

      4 => array(
        '2015-22-11',
        'credit#30',
        'debit#80'
        ),

      5 => array(
        '2015-23-11',
        'credit#65',
        'debit#34'
        ),

   );
```

My goal is to rearrange this array to something like this where the same dates become a key and the matched array where date is found becomes it's subsequent array.

```
   array(

     '2015-21-11' => array(
       0 => array(
         '2015-21-11',
         'credit#50',
         'debit#70'
       ),

      1 => array(

        '2015-21-11',
        'credit#80',
         'debit#30'
      )

    ),


   '2015-22-11' => array(

     0 =>array(
      '2015-22-11',

      'credit#80',

      'debit#90'

    ),

    1 => array(

      '2015-22-11',

      'credit#30',

      'debit#80'

    ),

  ),

 '2015-23-11' => array(

    0 => array(

      '2015-23-11',

      'credit#65',

      'debit#34'

      )

  ),
```

);

Currently i can't group the transactions by a particular date. If i can rearrange the array to my preferred array, it will help me to show a particular day's transaction to my users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just go through your array and rearrange it as you like in a new array. It might not be the fastest code, but its quite flexible and easy to understand.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
//create the array containing the newly sorted data
$trans_sorted = [];

//go through each element of our array
foreach ($trans_arr as $trans) {

   //check if entry with that date exists already 
   //$trans[0] is the date
   If (!isset($trans_sorted[$trans[0]])) {

      //if it does not exist yet, initialize an empty array
      $trans_sorted[$trans[0]] = [];
   }

   //add our transaction to this date
   $trans_sorted[$trans[0]][] = $trans;
}

//print_r($trans_sorted)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!